# How to configure ocelot api-gateway net 6.0, in order to redirect request to a controller in the same web-application (same host and port)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, api-gateway, ocelot

target framework net 6.0 ocelot 18.0.0

**program.cs**:

```
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var ocelotConfig = builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "ocelot.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseOcelot();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**ocelot.json**:

```
{
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseAddress": "https://localhost:7249"
  },
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/WeatherForecast",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7249
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gtw/WeatherForecast",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**WeatherForcastController.cs**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DemoApiGateway.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

When I try to call either https://localhost:7249/gtw/WeatherForecast or directly https://localhost:7249/api/WeatherForecast I get response Http 404.

P.S.
In earlier version of .net core (2.2) it works. But it's deprecated and I'd like to rebuild to LTS version of .net.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because Ocelot processes the upstream call to `/api/WeatherForecast`, starts the downstream call to `/gtw/WeatherForecast`, which is again processed by the Ocelot and never reaches the controller.
Minimal API does some [implicit magic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/middleware?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-6.0). In reality, your middleware pipeline looks like this:

```cs
app.UseRouting();       // added implicitly
app.UseOcelot();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(e =>   // added implicitly
{
    e.MapControllers();
});
```

The middleware order registration is essential: the incoming request is processed by every middleware in the order they are registered. There are multiple issues in your code:

- The `UseHttpsRedirection` should be called before `UseRouting` (which was added implicitly). To disable the implicit adding of the `UseRouting` you should call it explicitly in the correct place.
- The `UseAuthorization` should be called before `UseOcelot` if you are using authorization in your Ocelot configuration.
- Ocelot is a terminal middleware, which means nothing will be executed after the `UseOcelot`. It means `Endpoints` middleware won't have a chance to handle the request and dispatch it to the `WeatherForecastController`. To register Ocelot after `Endpoints` you should call `UseEndpoints` explicitly in the correct place.

The fixed code should be:

```cs
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(e =>
{
    e.MapControllers();
});
app.UseOcelot();
```