# How can I use the default controllers in an ASP.NET Web API to respond to requests when using Ocelot?

Tags: asp.net, .net-7.0, ocelot

I'm using Ocelot with .NET 7 in a simple API project that only has a WeatherForecast controller. I want to route all requests that begin with '/OtherRequest' to an external API on the domain 'respondingdomain.com', but locally respond to '/WeatherForecast' requests with the default controller. The application is running on port 5287

Here is my Program.cs and Ocelot.json file.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("ocelot.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true).Build();
builder.Services.AddOcelot();
builder.Services.AddControllers();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseOcelot().Wait();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/OtherRequest/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "respondingdomain.com",
          "Port": 443
        }
      ],
      "DelegatingHandlers": [
        "OcelotLoggingHandler"
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/OtherRequest/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE" ],
      "RouteIsCaseSensitive": false
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/weatherforecast",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5287
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/weatherforecast",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE" ],
      "RouteIsCaseSensitive": false

    }
  ]
  
}
```

The problem is that '/WeatherForecast' is not working and is responding with a 503 error."

Also I tried with this ocelot.json file

```
{
  "Routes": [
     {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/OtherRequest/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "respondingdomain.com",
          "Port": 443
        }
      ],
      "DelegatingHandlers": [
        "OcelotLoggingHandler"
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/OtherRequest/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
      "RouteIsCaseSensitive": false
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/weatherforecast",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5287
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/weatherforecast",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE" ],
      "RouteIsCaseSensitive": false

    }

  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration":

  {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:5287"
  }

}
```

I'm still getting a 503 error.

Note that the 'WeatherForecast' controller's GET method is working properly without Ocelot, and here is the controller code:

```
namespace ApiManager.Ocelot.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to map controllers before starting ocelot.

Comment: Check this answer to understand what @CodingMytra means: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74836503/how-to-configure-ocelot-api-gateway-net-6-0-in-order-to-redirect-request-to-a-c/75188338#75188338