# Ocelot Gateway Healthcheck

Tags: c#, health-check, ocelot

I want to add an Ocelot Gateway healthcheck, but

1. This is nowhere to be found as default nuget package from AspNetCore.HealthChecks.??? . Is this not done usually?
2. When adding the healthcheck myself, and mapping a healthcheck on startup, navigation to the url wants to redirect me to a downstream. (code below)

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    builder.Services.AddHealthChecks();
    builder.Configuration.AddOcelot(builder.Environment);

    var app = builder.Build();
    app.UseOcelot();
    app.MapHealthChecks("/_health", new HealthCheckOptions
    {
        ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
    });
    app.Run();
```

Anyone any clue on how to do this?

Comment: Ocelot is a gateway that redirects incoming requests to an underlying microservice (following the downstream-path) Since there is no downstream-path configured, because it is located on the same application, it tries to redirect but can't. Instead it would need to use the endpoint configured in the healthcheck. But it seems that gets ignored...

Comment: Ocelot is a terminal middleware, which means nothing registered in the pipeline after it is not executed. `MapHealthChecks` is related to the `Endpoints` middleware which is registered implicitly at the end of the pipeline (read after the Ocelot). Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74836503/how-to-configure-ocelot-api-gateway-net-6-0-in-order-to-redirect-request-to-a-c/75188338#75188338) for more info and tip on how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved thanks to Artur in comments above.
Just add `UseRouting()`, `MapHealthChecks()` and `UseEndpoints()` BEFORE the `UseOcelot()` method.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHealthChecks();
builder.Configuration.AddOcelot(builder.Environment);

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapHealthChecks("/_health", new HealthCheckOptions
{
    ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
});
app.UseEndpoints(e =>
{
    e.MapControllers();
});
app.UseOcelot();
app.Run();
```